# Geopandas Rotate function

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I would like to use the use the `geopandas.rotate()` function to rotate all features in a `geodataframe` based on an attribute in a column. I am successful if I just select one feature. However for multiple rows, I believe I need to create a for loop.

```
new_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=foo.columns)
for index, row in foo.iterrows():
    bar = foo[foo[row]].rotate(foo[rotation_col], origin='center')
    new_gdf=new_gdf.append(bar)
```

When I attempt to write the for loop, I get a type error unhashable type: `'Polygon'`. I also tried writing an `.apply()` function. I am not sure I am doing this one right. But this is what I have:

```
foo_new = foo.apply(foo.rotate(foo.rotation_col, origin='center'))
```

I can provide more info as needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to rotate `shapely.Polygon`, not `GeoPandas.GeoSeries`, so you need to use shapely to do that.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

p1 = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])
p2 = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (2, 1)])

g = gpd.GeoSeries([p1, p2])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=g)
gdf['angle'] = [25, 45]

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    rotated = shapely.affinity.rotate(row['geometry'], row['angle'])
    gdf.loc[index, 'geometry'] = rotated
```

Comment: Much appreciated. There is a rotate method in geopandas. I am not sure why it couldnt do it in a loop. only worked when it was one feature.

Comment: Because GeoPandas `rotate` is rotating all elements in GeoSeries by the same angle. If you do a loop, you are no more passing GeoSeries but, in your case, shapely.Polygon and GeoPandas `rotate` needs GeoSeries.